# Create a function that, given an array and declared a variable, returns true or false if the variable exceeds each element of the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop, if-statement

I would like to create a program from a function that, given an array made up of a series of numbers and declared a variable with a value, returns true if the value exceeds each of the numbers in array and otherwise returns false.

```
let array = [5000, 5000, 3]
let value = 2300;


function compare_Values(table,number){
    
    
  for(let i = 0; i <= table.length; i++){
    
      if(number < table[i]){
        
        var result = "FALSE: failed ";

      } else{
       var result = "TRUE: if passed";
    }
          return result
  }
}



console.log(compare_Values(array,value))
```

I don't know why the result returns **FALSE**. The value does not exceed each of the elements in the table.
Can someone help me? I don't know where is my mistake.

Comment: _"I don't know why the result returns TRUE. The value does not exceed each of the elements in the table."_ - but it exceeds the last one, and since you are _overwriting_ `result` in each loop iteration, of course only the last value you assign, "survives."

Comment: Because each iteration of the loop redeclares the already-declared `result` variable, and only the last iteration counts since after that last test (where 3 *is* less than 2300) declares `result` as `FALSE...` I'd suggest learning about [`Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every): [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/fsqx9rvo/).

Comment: Initialize your result variable as true before the loop, and inside the loop, only check if the current array element is greater that your number - if so, set the result variable to false now, and `break` out of your loop.

Comment: "if the value exceeds **each** of the numbers in array" -- this is somewhat misleading, atleast to me. It's not clear what the problem wants you to do. If any number in the array is exceeded, then you must return false? If this is it, then CBroe and David are correct.

Comment: You should probably use `Array.every` of something to check this?

Comment: It was my fall, sorry. I have just changed it. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood it correctly, then there are lots of ways to solve this problem, but I'll show you 2 of them.

By using a common for loop -- you just initialize a result (`res`) outsite the for loop and then stops the iteration if any element is lower than the `n`

```
function solve(arr, n) {
    let res = true;
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length && res; i++) {
        res = n <= arr[i];
    }

    return res;
}
```

By using the [`Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) method:

```
let arr = [5000, 5000, 4000];
let n = 2300;

console.log(arr.every(v => n <= v));
```

Comment: @somethinghere no, it doesn't. Look at my for condition: i < arr.length **&& res**

Comment: Indeed. In that case you might also be better off with a `find`, tbf.

Comment: Thank you very much @Matheus, looking at your code I could see my error. It's a rookie mistake. As you well say, there are different ways to solve the exercise.

Answer (score 0):

You should put return outside the for loop

```
let array = [5000, 5000, 3]
let value = 2300;


function compare_Values(table,number){
  var result;  
  for(let i = 0; i < table.length; i++){    
      if(number < table[i]){        
        result = "TRUE: if passed";
      } else{
       result = "FALSE: failed";
       return result;
    }
  }
  return result
}



console.log(compare_Values(array,value))
```

Comment: That still doesn't solve the issue, that `result` gets overwritten in each loop iteration. With `let value = 5300;`, your code still outputs FALSE: failed.

Comment: @CBroe updated. although .every() makes more sense to use `table.every(x => number < x)`